# Google cloud - cloubduild and app variabile substitution in trigger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, app.yaml

I'm using cloudbuild to deploy new version of my app when a new commit appears in github.
Everything is working good.

Now I'm trying to setup a variable substitution in the trigger configuration, because I want to put my version number in the trigger once, so that I can find the deployed correct version without modifying cloudbuild configuration file.
Variabile substitution works great in my cloudbuild file, for example:
(cloudbuild.yaml)

```
# TEST: PRINT VARIABLE IN LOG
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'echo', '${_VERSION}']

# DEPLOY APP
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "-v", "${_VERSION}", "app.yaml"]
  dir: 'frontend'
  timeout: "20m"
```

${_VERSION} is correctly replaced with the string I put into my trigger.

Now I want to obtain the same result in app.yaml file, substituting an env variabile, something like:
(app.yaml)

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: backend

env_variables:
  VERSION: "${_VERSION}"
  TEST_ENV: "read from google"
```

When I read TEST_ENV from my app, it works, but _VERSION is not replaced.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform this step

```
# DEPLOY APP
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "-v", "${_VERSION}", "app.yaml"]
  dir: 'frontend'
  timeout: "20m"
```

The `app.yaml` is provided as-is to the gcloud command, and it's not evaluated. You have to update it manually. Something like this

```
# REPLACE: PUT THE CORRECT VALUE IN APP.YAML FILE
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'sed', "-i", "sed -i "s/\$${_VERSION}/${_VERSION}/g", 'app.yaml']
```

Of course if you let the

```
env_variables:
  VERSION: "${_VERSION}"
```

as-is in your `app.yaml` file. You can change this replacement string

Comment: Thanks @guillaume blaquiere , your answer didn't work (I think something is bad in the args string) but you pointed me on the right path. I solved using the syntax breakout, I'll post my solution too.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add this solution in case someone has problems with the one proposed by giullade (in my case, cloudbuild gave me an error in executing the sed command).

I also changed my replacement string to one more readable and to avoid escaping the $ sign.

```
# Step 0: REPLACE variables in app.yaml file
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  dir: 'backend'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    sed -i "s/__VERSION/${_VERSION}/g" app-staging.yaml
```

and in my app.yaml:

```
env_variables:
  VERSION_ENV: "__VERSION"
```